# Java Recursion Method That Doubles An Amount

Tags: java, recursion

If you work for a month and first day you get paid 1 cent and day two 2 cents. Each day the amount doubles. And the user input a day and it will display how much money you will be paid in that day.

How can this be done with recursion.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? I suggest using use a `long` or `double` instead of an `int`.  If you don't show any effort, it doesn't encourage anyone to help you.

Comment: @peterLawrey well I am still trying to figure out the algorithm on how it can be done using recursion. How can using long or double would change? I am trying to double the amount each day for example day 3 I would be paid 4, day 4 I would be paid 8 and so on. Thank you.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @1615903 I am sorry I was not trying for someone to write the code for me, I wanted to understand the algorithm of it. I was simply practicing recursion since it is very tricky for beginners. sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
public long amountmoney (long days){

if(days<=1){

return 1;}

else{

return 2*amountmoney (days-1);}

}
```

Comment: Yes this works thank you so much.

Comment: You can write this as `public static long amount(int days) { return days <= 1 ? 1 : 2 * amount(days - 1); }`

Answer (score 0):

Basically its an infinite series . 1-2-4-8-16 and so on. So basically the nth term would be 2^(N-1) where N represent Nth day of payment. Good luck !

```
public long cashPayment(int DayNumber)
{

return 2^(DayNumber-1);

}
```

Comment: Thank you this explains it a lot. I was thinking in a different way. Thank you.

Comment: Note 2^^n is actually `2L << n` or `Math.pow(2, n)` as `^` mean XOR not power of